# unable to link customer managed key within azure storage account get the error Your system-assigned identity does not have access to the key vault

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I am unable to link a customer managed key for a storage account, it complains with the error below.

Assuming the storage account is called `storage123`, I granted access to the principal called `storage123`, and the role granted was `Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User`

`Your system-assigned identity does not have access to the key vault. You can request access to the key vault by sending your admin the object ID from Identity under Security + networking when system-assigned status is enabled`

Not sure what to do, I have got the key vault administrator role assigned to myself, so I dont think the issue is from my side, unsure of what else to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide more details like error image from the portal or any code you tried. @learner

Comment: Please include access configuration page of key vault from your portal @learner

Comment: Added the access configuration page which confirms its rbac model.

Answer (score 0):

When you select System Managed Identity, you will no longer use a service principle that you created. It is the Object ID of your storage account that needs to have access to the key vault.

The error message clearly says that you should use the Object ID from Identity under Security + Networking when system-Assigned status is enabled.

So go to the storage account and find the object ID from Identity under Security + Networking and assign it the required permission on key vault and that should be it.

Comment: Its a catch 22, I cannot see object ID, if system identity is selected it wants me to choose the key vault etc, if the storage account is called xxx, I believe the object to search for when assigning a role to the object ID would  be xxx, you do not have an object ID without selecting the KV first, and I cant select the KV as its complaining about permissions.

Comment: I just tried the same by creating a storage account and keyvault and works fine. What access do you have on the key vault? Are you using RBAC or Access policy on your key vault? I just created a new Access policy on the key vault and granted myself all the key permissions. Then created a new key and I was able to select the same key from the storage account and could save it without errors.